# Facebook Error (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action (PHP)

Tags: php, facebook, operating-system, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I am posting on facebook profile, pages and groups using my webapp.since morning it showing error "Exception occured, code: 200 with message: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action".
I added all permissions required for posting.

```
 $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl( ["public_profile", "user_groups","publish_actions","email","user_location","user_photos",    "user_likes","manage_pages","user_birthday","user_status","read_stream"] );

$requestPage = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', 'post_on_page_id?fields=access_token');
                        $responsePage = $requestPage->execute();
                        $resultPage = $responsePage->getGraphObject()->asArray();
                        $pageToken = $resultPage['access_token'];
                        $facebookSession = new FacebookSession($pageToken);
                        $response = (new FacebookRequest( $facebookSession, 'POST', 'post_on_page_id/photos',array('source' => new CURLFile("$userPhoto", 'image/png'),'message' => "$message")))->execute()->getGraphObject();
                        $page_post_id=$response->getProperty('id');
```

And one more problem is that my app fetching profile, all groups and pages. It's showing connected profile image, group cover image and page profile image in chrome, but not in other browsers and operating systems.

My app url is http://picstun.com/socialsharing/

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are only requesting permission for: My public profile and email address.

Comment: i addedd all reqire scope at login url.                                                 $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl( ["public_profile", "user_groups","publish_actions","email","user_location","user_photos",    "user_likes","manage_pages","user_birthday","user_status","read_stream"] );

Comment: getLoginUrl() expects only 3 parameters. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3