# Facebook-sdk Gives "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" on auto post with codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

Here is the my code..

```
public function autopost(){

$this->load->library('facebook', array(
  'appId' => '15704450865*****',
  'secret' => '9ef9e145108f7331d677209b62c*****'
  ));

$user = $this->facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
$params = array(
  "access_token" => $access_token ,
  "message" => "my message goes here.",
  "link" => "http://www.sakkigoni.com/",
 // "picture" => "http://i.imgur.com/lHkOsiH.png",
  "name" => "How to Auto Post on Facebook with PHP",
  "caption" => "www.pontikis.net",
  "description" => " description goes here."
  );

if($user){
  try {

    $ret = $this->facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $params);
    echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook Personal Profile';
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}else{
  echo "<a href='".$this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email, publish_actions'))."'>Login with Facebook</a>";
}
```

}

when I run the above code and login on facebook to auto post.Only admin user of app is authorized to post in timeline but other user shows this error

```
"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"
```

i have tried these too but doesn't work in me

[same #200 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471015/facebook-error-200-the-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application-to-perform-this)

[same #200 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140559/how-to-fix-200-the-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application-to-perform-this-ac)

Comment: “Autoposting” is not allowed; if you post to user timelines, then the user has to type in the message and actively trigger the post, each single time. // Did you get your app’s use of the permission reviewed by Facebook yet?

Comment: no  i still havent got facebook permission . is it because of it? and what do you mean by "Autoposting" is not allowed ? does it mean even if we get permission from facebook , is it not applicable ?

Comment: Yes, of course it is because of that. The docs mention the need for review and describe the process in great detail, and if you grant that permission as the app admin, there is also a clear warning message in that regard that shows up in the login dialog – how have you managed to ignore all that?

Comment: And by “autoposting is not allowed”, I meant exactly what I wrote: Your app is not allowed to specify the message of a share/post for the user, they have to type it in themselves. And you app is not allowed to post in the name of a user when it feels like it - the user has to actively trigger it every time. If you have not done so yet, then you should go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) first of all now.

Answer (score 0):

**If it works for the App admin, but not for anyone else, you probably forgot to send `publish_actions` through review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review**

Also, autoposting is not allowed and the message must be 100% user generated. You MUST read the platform policy before creating any App: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

In other words: You will never get `publish_actions` approved for autoposting and a predefined message.

Comment: i do have sent `publish_actions ` as in code above  also can i send message data from form inputs , like: `$_post['message']` as 100% user generated

Comment: open the first link of my answer and learn about login review, that´s what you need. publish_actions needs to be reviewed before you can go public with it.